# In one hour’s difference or one hours difference

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

One hour’s difference or
One hours difference

My daughters teacher is saying the second but I believe she is wrong

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples on a dictionary or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not. Here are some online free references that are commonly recognized,Wikipedia, Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, VOA, Google Ngram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hour's is correct as the apostrophe indicates possessive tense.

"An hour's worth of your time" (example)